# How to adjust spacing and alignment between legend symbol and text in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm getting some weird and seemingly random spaces between the symbol and text labels in the legend for the Qgis print composer. How can I set the symbols and text to align left/right or divide the symbols into one centered column and the text in another?

Also, in the legend currently, the third entry, "10m interim..." is not displaying the symbol at the proper size. It should be the largest yellow circle.

[image: Screenshot. Note different sized symbols and erratic spacings between symbols and labels.]

Comment: Are you able to share your project and a small subset of the data? I'd like to see if this is a bug in QGIS which can be fixed before the next release but would need a demonstration project to investigate.

Comment: ndawson, how can i share a data ?

Answer (score 1):

Used this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86672/how-to-resize-symbols-in-the-qgis-print-composer-legend), basically a work-around to reduce the size of the symbols on the map, create the legend, disable auto-refresh, and then set the map symbology back to the preferred size.