# How to style graduated using size-scale field

Tags: qgis, legend, print-composer

Is it possible to style based on size-scale field using graduated symbol but instead of using color ramp, I would like to display its size. I would also like to display this in the legend in the map composer. It would be nice if I could also apply this if I'll use svg marker (example 2nd image below).

From this:

[image]

to something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to figure out how to achieve this but I don't know if this is the best way to do this. I used Rule-based styling, screenshots below:

[image]

And then I individually set the sizes of svg marker for each "category":

[image]

And this is what it looked like in my canvass:

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't like the results I have in print composer:

[image]

I've read a similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86672/how-to-resize-symbols-in-the-qgis-print-composer-legend) but based on the 2nd answer of that post, the sizes of the circles in the legend were different from the canvass.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the initial colour ramp and then change each symbol and range manually by double clicking on it.