# Creating QGIS legend showing different size points from set scale field?

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend

I have created a map with different sized points based on another attribute using the set scale field in QGIS v2.8.4. See map image. [image]

I am trying to create a legend like this previous thread showing different size bubbles with the range of attributes. How can I do this?

[Resizing symbols in QGIS Print Composer legend?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86672/how-to-resize-symbols-in-the-qgis-print-composer-legend)

Answer (score 3):

If you want also graduated color in legend, QGIS recommends you set graduation style on color and data-defined size. This works well on map canvas, but I dont get it work in composer legend.

[image]

So my solution is, first for size graduated symbol you have to use *Graduated style* in layer properties. As a *Method* choose **Size**. This will give you size graduation of one color.

[image]

Than you have to set **colors manually** double click on individual categories.

*Note:*

Maybe **Data defined override** will works for you. Try also set data defined override to changing fill of symbol with expression (in Style window click on *Change...*, select *Simple marker* and set data define override on *Fill*). You can use for example `color_rgb()` for counting color using values from fileds. But this doesn't work for me neither, maybe it's bug, because if I set random color expression for *Fill* it works well, but if I use fields for values it doesn't show legend properly (QGIS 2.18.3., Linux).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does not appear that my version of QGIS has a method box to choose size in the graduated style (layer properties). I will download a newer version and try again! Thanks.